# unable to change the centre point of a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, ipod

so, in my ios pacman game, after a collision is detected between pacman and an enemy brick this method runs.  It is suppose to stop the game timer, show the start button and return pacman to his start point.  The method functions correctly except that pacman stays where he is and never returns to his start point, am I making an obvious mistake in changing the centre point?

```
-(void)lose{
    [self stopTimer];
    self.play.hidden = FALSE;
    _start = CGPointMake(30, 247);
    self.pacman.center = self.start;
    [self.pacman setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Thanks for any help,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

if you do like this is there any problem.

```
self.pacman.center = CGPointMake(30, 247);
```

Comment: means some where else you went wrong.once check IBOutlet and all other things related to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log the center of pacman before and after setup new value:

```
NSLog(@"Pacman's center: (%f, %f)", self.pacman.center.x, self.pacman.center.y);
```